# Mysql complex order by

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have 3 columns in my table

1. **status**        enum('Completed','Incomplete','In Progress')
2. **severity**      enum('High','Low','Moderate')
3. **created**       datetime

Now currently i am ordering by `severity ASC created DESC status DESC`. which is not working right. This is how i want it to be listed.

1. Incomplete  - High
2. Incomplete  - moderate
3. Incomplete  - low
4. In Progress - High
5. In Progress  - moderate
6. In Progress  - low
7. Completed - High
8. Completed  - moderate
9. Completed  - low

Comment: What do you end up with?  What happens if you put status first then created then severity?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As well as Andomar's solution, I'd consider having proper tables for status and severity. Not enums.

You can imply sort order from the key of these tables, but I'd probably have a "SortOrder" column for future use.Then you can JOIN the tables and order by the SortOrder.

No need repeat the CASE in every query that needs it

Edit: Simplifying Andomar's idea...

```
order by
    case status
       when 'Incomplete' then 1
       when 'In Progress' then 2
       when 'Completed' then 3
    END,
    case severity
       when 'High' then 1
       when 'Moderate' then 2
       when 'Low' then 3
    END
```

Comment: +1 Suggested this to Andomar as well, but I wasn't sure if this actually possible.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a `case` to order rows like that:

```
select  *
from    YourTable
order by
        case 
        when status = 'Incomplete' and severity = 'High' then 1
        when status = 'Incomplete' and severity = 'Moderate' then 2
        ...
        end
```

Comment: +1: But this question really demonstrates why using a natural key isn't always the best idea.  A lookup table using a numeric primary key would make this much simpler & robust if more severity/etc values get added.

Comment: +1 This should be able to be simplified to multiple `case`s shouldn't it? One `case` for status and one for severity? Would save OP having to write out all permutations.

Answer (score 0):

You can store Status and Severity as numbers,
the use:

```
SELECT ... FROM ... ... ORDER BY STATUS [ASC/DESC], SEVERITY [ASC/DESC]
```

ASC or DESC will depend on wich numbers you choose.

To have severity and status as text you can use a IF/Switch or a INNER JOIN if you want more Status/Severity